# Powershell to remove all file extensions in sharepoint online library through mapped network drive

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, network-drive

Hello and thanks in advance for the help. I am attempting to remove an extra extension that was added to documents in a library due to a security breach. When i manually remove the extension ".easy2lock" the file becomes available. However, when i try to do this programmatically via powershell it works, but not for folders with long paths. Does anyone know how to get around this in powershell?

[image]

I've tried tried updating my registry to allow long paths, however, i don't believe that has any affect on
here is the script and error i recieve:
[image]

```
[string]$DeleteBadExtension = ".easy2lock_read_me"
[string]$BadExtension = ".easy2lock"
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$BadExtension" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $BadExtension, [string]::Empty}
Get-ChildItem *$DeleteBadExtension -Recurse | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to take your word for it that the files are usable after changing the name, that hasn't been my experience. To be able to access long paths in powershell you'll need to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter. Unfortunately the `-Path` parameter will be the default used when piping. `-LiteralPath` does take pipeline input by propertyname so you can either manipulate the object removing path and adding literal path like this

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$BadExtension" -Recurse |
    Select-Object Name,Basename,Extension,@{n='LiteralPath';e={"\\?\$($_.fullname)"}} |
        Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $BadExtension}
```

Or you can use a `Foreach-Object` or foreach loop and use the required syntax `\\?\` for the path.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$BadExtension" -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath "\\?\$($_.FullName)" -NewName ($_.Name -replace ‘$BadExtension’)
}
```

**Edit**

Since the basename is the desired filename (just without the unwanted extension) you can use the basename as the newname. All four examples have been tested and confirmed to work. If it's not working for you then there is something else going on.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *$BadExtension -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath "\\?\$($_.FullName)" -NewName ($_.name -replace $BadExtension)
}

Get-ChildItem -Filter *$BadExtension -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath "\\?\$($_.FullName)" -NewName $_.basename
}

Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$BadExtension" -Recurse |
    Select-Object Name,@{n='LiteralPath';e={"\\?\$($_.fullname)"}} |
        Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $BadExtension}

Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$BadExtension" -Recurse |
    Select-Object Basename,@{n='LiteralPath';e={"\\?\$($_.fullname)"}} |
        Rename-Item -NewName {$_.baseName}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I get the following error with the script you provided, "Cannot evaluate parameter 'newname' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input"

Comment: One other interesting thing i've noted, is that in my original script, the remove-item path works just fine but not the re-name. This one works:  [string]$DeleteBadExtension = ".easy2lock_read_me" Get-ChildItem *$DeleteBadExtension -Recurse | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }

Comment: I edited my answer, I can’t test at the moment so let me know if that works

Comment: No luck, this is the error i get: "The filename, directory name, or volume lable syntax is incorrect". based on my research the 2nd period may be tripping it up. for example, my documents look like this:   MyDocument.xlsx.easy2lock

Comment: My testing on normal file and folder worked with both examples. I’ll have to make a file like yours and test with that. Try removing the string empty. When you are just using replace to remove something, the second argument can be omitted. So just ($_.name -replace $Badextension)

Comment: Also, can you confirm if basename is just the file.ext ?

Comment: Correct the basename is  .SLDDRW and the extension is .easy2lock.  This is what i've tried so far: [string]$BadExtension=".easy2lock"                                                         
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*$BadExtension" -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -LiteralPath "\\?\$($_.FullName)" -NewName($_.Name -replace $BadExtension, [string]::Empty)}     ...do i need to remove the string in the variable when I remove the string in the second argument? I've tried both and get the same "the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax..." Is it possible it's SharePoint limitatio?

Comment: No the basename should be "filename.SLDDRW"

Comment: Correct, the basename is filename.slddrw